# Xna GameEngine for crossplatform

Tags: c#, android, ios, xna

i wanna start writing game for android/ios with my friends and we're looking for good game engine for XNA c# programing can someone recommend something to start with expect unity/udkengine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> good game engine for XNA c# programing

There are many.

You can check [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) and [OpenTK](http://www.opentk.com/).

> i wanna start writing game for android/ios

Try [MonoTouch](http://xamarin.com/monotouch)